# slicing behaviour question of a list of lists

Tags: python, function, slice

I got a function like

```
def f():
    ...
    ...
    return [list1, list2]
```

this returns a list of lists

```
[[list1.item1,list1.item2,...],[list2.item1,list2.item2,...]]
```

now when I do the following:

```
for i in range(0,2):print f()[i][0:10]
```

it works and print the lists sliced

but if i do

```
print f()[0:2][0:10]
```

then it prints the lists ignoring the [0:10] slicing.

Is there any way to make the second form work or do I have to loop every time to get the desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why these two behave differently is because `f()[0:2][0:10]` works like this:

1. `f()` gives you a list of lists.
2. `[0:2]` gives you a list containing the first two elements in the list of lists.  Since the elements in the list of lists are lists, this is *also* a list of lists.
3. `[0:10]` gives you a list containing the first ten elements in the list of lists that was produced in step 2.

In other words, `f()[0:2][0:10]` starts with a list of lists, then takes a sublist of that list of lists (which is also a list of lists), and then takes a sublist of the second list of lists (which is also a list of lists).

In contrast, `f()[i]` actually extracts the `i`-th element out of your list of lists, which is just a simple list (not a list of lists).  Then, when you apply `[0:10]`, you are applying it to the simple list that you got from `f()[i]` and not to a list of lists.

The bottom line is that any solution that gives the desired behavior will have to access a single array element like `[i]` at some point, rather than working only with slices like `[i:j]`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I got a much better picture on the behavior of slicing with list of lists.

Answer (score 10):

The second slice slices the sequence returned from the first slice, so yes, you will have to loop somehow in order to slice within:

```
[x[0:10] for x in f()[0:2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic loop would be:

```
for list in f()[0:2]:
    print list[0:10]
```

But depending on what you want to achieve, list comprehension might be even better.

Or you make use of Pythons [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
def print_sub(x):
    print x[0:10]

map(print_sub, f()[0:2])
```

One way or the other, there is no way to not iterate over the list and achieve the desired result.

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(slice(0, 10))` also works there in `map()`.

Comment: attention, you are redefining the `list` keyword in your code - better to use a variable name like `l` or `my_list`.